# Ajax breaks jQuery scripts on page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently working on a website that you'll find here: http://steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/. I used an ajax effect that I found online at CSS-Tricks to dynamically load content from another php page and animate it (fade in and fade out) when a navigation tab is clicked.

I have managed to get this working fine, as you will see (please note the only two working pages are "Home" and "Experience RGW"), however, all of the jQuery scripts in my document that apply to elements within the div that reloads are broken when the content is dynamically generated.

As a quick example, take a look at the text resize tool beneath the image rotator on the home page and try changing the font size. Now, click on the "Experience RGW" tab and scroll down to the text resize tool again. Notice that now that we've loaded in experience.php dynamically within the "#ajax" div, the script doesn't work. Also, if you click on the "Home" link now, you will also notice that the image rotator doesn't work.

I've looked high and low online and through multiple forums to try and figure out how to fix this, and I believe I have to incorporate the jQuery .live function, to apply the script to any element, whether it's currently visible or not. Otherwise, document.ready only runs the scripts once after the DOM loads and will not affect the ajax loaded content. Is that correct? If so, how do I apply that to multiple jQuery files executed on my page?

Well, this is totally driving me crazy and I've tried hard to get it, but I just can't quite figure it out. I'm fairly new to jQuery, but am trying to learn fast. I would post some of the code here, but there is a lot involved in this question. :)

If anyone would be willing to shoot out a quick answer, or a few lines of code, I'd greatly appreciate it.

FYI: The script that runs the ajax effect is in ./scripts/page.js. Also, please remember that I currently have only the Home page and Experience RGW page working correctly, so please don't waste time trying to diagnose problems on the other pages. I haven't gotten to them yet. :)

Here is a link to some of the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taylortsantles/R33YV/.

Thanks,
Taylor

Comment: I normally just design the HTML around a generalized structure. That way when you do a get request for the PHP pages instead you can just pass the content to the #ajax div. This way you are just updating the content of the currently loaded div instead of loading a whole new page. You just have to use more logic in your PHP.

Comment: Looks like you may have fixed it.  Your website is applying the event correctly.  Is it fixed?

Comment: Hey nate, the text resize is working now. I used the code from seacode. However, I don't know how to do the same for the other scripts now. You can see how he added this line of code in his post below: // Rebind any events
documenttextsizer.setup("text-resize");

Comment: Guys... question. Can I use the jQuery getScript function and run it whenever ajax is called on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebind any events after dynamically loading in elements to a page, as Javascript sees these as totally new DOM elements.

You can achieve this by modifying the code you use to update the page:

```
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#ajax")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #ajax", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav li").removeClass("on");
                    $("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").parent().addClass("on");

                    // Rebind any events
                    documenttextsizer.setup("text-resize");

                });
            });
    };

});
```

This applies to any events that happen WITHIN the updated elements in the page. So after the comment "//Rebind any events" you can add others as they are required! Hope that helps :)

Comment: Something to bear in mind also is that this system of updating the pages won't play especially nice with bots that don't understand Javascript!

Comment: this shouldn't be an issue, because each page is it's own static page. So, bots should read the pages individually, as they are. The ajax effect is simply loading that new content within a certain area using a fade effect.

Comment: Hey seacode, the docmenttextsizer.setup("text-resize"); worked! How do I do this for the other scripts?

Comment: Taylor, you simply need to call the function you wanted again. What other scripts do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I'm behind a proxy and can't see your page, but it sounds like the events are not being re-attached to the content created through ajax.

I'll try to explain, when your page loads the first time, you are attaching jQuery events to DOM objects on document.ready(), this function will be called only once.

Every time you drop DOM objects and create new ones with the ajax response, these new objects never get jQuery events attached again, since the document.ready() function didn't fire.

You can try putting your event-attaching code in a different function and invoke that function on document.ready() AND after every DOM modification (your ajax call to change the tab content).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to articulate this. I definitely understand the problem, I just don't know how to apply the solution (aka - code it). That's where I'm at.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a breakdown in the order of executing code.

1. page loads
2. load event fires and sets up elements
3. click event
4. ajax loads the new page

The new page doesn't have any events set to it.  Two solutions

1. use "live" links in the window.load event callback
2. use run the page load code again.

Solution 1 is nice but if you have an specific plugin used then it won't be the total solution.

Solution 2 can be implemented by pulling out your code in window.load and wrapping in another function. Just all it onload and then in the callback when the ajax loads.

I know how frustrating is can be.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Nate, could you please elaborate on how I would use the live links in the window.load event? I've tried something to this effect, but am not familiar enough with jQuery to code it correctly.

Comment: I can but I need to see some of the code that you are working with.  Can you edit your original post to show HTML and js? Better yet is to post a link using jsfiddle.

Comment: Using .live() will work great if they're all jQuery events but Taylor is using a custom javascript function to change the text size. Refer to my post for code.

Comment: @natedavisolds Sorry about that, been looking at code far too long today ;)

Comment: Can I use something different for the javascript text resize effect?

Comment: Here is a link to the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taylortsantles/R33YV/. It doesn't include all of the scripts, because most of them are in different files stored on my server. However, the javascript I included is for the ajax effect. Thank you so much.